# Run "sudo -u" without asking for the current user's password

Tags: linux, sudo

I'm sorry if I missed an answer here. But I did Google this and couldn't find a straight forward answer.

I want to enable the `apache` user to run commands as another user, but when I do:

`echo "PASSWORD" | sudo -u another_user -S echo "X"`

**Inside a PHP script**, I get:

`[sudo] password for apache:`

The `apache` user doesn't have a password, so I can't just output it in order to run `sudo`. Any way I can enable the `apache` user to run `sudo` for a specific set of commands under the `another_user` account without a password?

---

**PS.:** I currently have

`apache  ALL=(yourhost)  /usr/bin/git --git-dir=/* --work-tree=/* pull origin master`

on my `sudoers` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lookup up "NOPASSWD" usage in the sudoers file.

as in:

`apache ALL=(yourhost) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/git --git-dir=/* --work-tree=/* pull origin master`

Whether this is a good idea or not, is a different discussion.

Comment: Yeah, I know it isn't exactly the safest thing in the world, but at least i'm narrowing the `NOPASSWD` to only 1 very specific command. Thanks!